# Execute carbon deployment manually

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When you deploy manually a .car inside WSO2 (ESB), wso2 deploys the file and it's done.
I would like to trigger manually this action.

My purpose is to send a .car file inside my ./carbonapps/ and deploy it.
I'm looking for a request in Java (executed by sh) or a web request.
Do you know how to do that ?

Thank you for you time :)

Comment: I don't quite understand the usecase. You want to deploy a carbonapp, but you don't have access to the filesystem so you want to do that through a webservice call?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm not clear. I want to put my .car files into the right folder "/carbonapps" and declench the processus of deployment. The fact is i have multiple servers and i don't want to restart every server or deploy one by one. (I work with Jenkins, so i want to call a kind of webservice, or a command line(?) )

Comment: I think the simplest way is to add a batch file or shell script running the copy command. You can create one (or two) per project and then do something like:
rm ./carbonapps/[projectname]-*

Comment: You mean "cp" command ? If yes, this is not my question. WSO2 uses a whole script to takes a .car and deploys all of his artefacts. I need to execute this script by myself.

Comment: Ah, I was still typing and apparently pressed enter during half my answer. Basically there is no way to manually NOT trigger that script when you put a file in the carbonapps folder. You can either script the copying, so write the .car somewhere else and at your call copy the file to the carbonapps folder which will automatically trigger deployment OR you can configure deployment in the pom.xml and have maven deploy. You can steer that behaviour using '-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true' (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Deploying+a+CAR+File+with+the+Maven+Plug-In)

Comment: I'll try to put a file inside my carbonapps folder and see if wso2esb declench his processus

Comment: Hi Robyn, any luck? I'd like to hear what solution you ended up with and why

Comment: I tried this morning to put my file into my "carbonapps" folder, and it works perfectly, thank you! I didn't find wich script is looking for modification in this folder, but i don't have to worry anymore. So, when i delete a file and reupload an other one, WSO2ESB undeployed the old one and deploy my new .car . Thank you again